# readOnGadget for a Q_GAGDET inside a Q_GADGET not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qmetaobject

I have a "top level" `Q_GADGET` and, inside this `Q_GADGET`, I have a pointer to another `Q_GADGET`. I am trying to use the function readOnGadget to display the values stored by both objects. I can do this just fine with the top level `Q_GADGET`, however the values read from the inner `Q_GADGET` are wrong. Here's my code:

Q_GADGETS:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
#include <QObject>

//Nested Q_GADGET
struct P2D {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(P2D p2d READ getP2D )
    Q_PROPERTY(float m_x READ getX WRITE setX)
    Q_PROPERTY(float m_y READ getY WRITE setY)



public:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    P2D getP2D() {return *this;}
    float getX() {return this->m_x;}
    void setX(float x) {this->m_x = x;}
    float getY() {return this->m_y;}
    void setY(float y) {this->m_y = y;}

}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(P2D)

//Main Q_GADGET
struct Player {
    Q_GADGET

public:
    enum class CarType {
        NO_CAR = 0,
        SLOW_CAR,
        FAST_CAR,
        HYPER_CAR
    }; Q_ENUM(CarType)

    Q_PROPERTY(Player player READ getPlayer)
    Q_PROPERTY(int m_speed READ getSpeed WRITE setSpeed)
    Q_PROPERTY(CarType m_carType READ getCarType)
    Q_PROPERTY(P2D* p2d READ getP2D )


    Player getPlayer() { return *this;}
    int getSpeed() {return this->m_speed;}
    void setSpeed(int speed) {this->m_speed = speed;}
    CarType getCarType() { return m_carType;}
    P2D* getP2D() {return this->p2d;}


public:
    CarType m_carType;
    int m_speed;
    P2D *p2d;

}; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Player)

#endif
```

Main:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include "example.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QPointer>

void* pointer = nullptr;

void gadgetExplorer(void *ptr, const char* s)
{
    //Receives pointer and access its meta-object
    qInfo() << "Pointer received is: " << ptr;
    int typeId = QMetaType::type(s);
    const QMetaObject *mo = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(typeId);
    //Prints class name
    qInfo() << "Q_GADGET: " << mo->className();

    //Iterates through properties
    QMetaProperty mp;
    for(int i = 1; i < mo->propertyCount(); i++)
    {
        mp = mo->property(i);
        qInfo() << "Q_PROPERTY: " << mp.name() << "Value: " << mp.readOnGadget(ptr);

        //1024 = user defined, so it's another gadget (P2D)
        if(int(mp.type()) == 1024)
            gadgetExplorer(pointer, mp.typeName());

    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<Player>();
    qRegisterMetaType<P2D>();
    qRegisterMetaType<P2D*>();

    Player p1;
    p1.setSpeed(30);
    p1.p2d = new P2D();
    p1.p2d->setX(10.0);
    p1.p2d->setY(25.0);
    qInfo() << "Pointer to inner Q_GADGET: " << &p1.p2d;
    pointer = &p1.p2d;
    gadgetExplorer(&p1, "Player");
    qInfo() << "Value of m_x outside funtion :" << p1.p2d->getX();


    return a.exec();
}
```

The output I get from the code is:

```
Pointer to inner Q_GADGET:  0x7ffdb82e3418
Pointer received is:  0x7ffdb82e3410
Q_GADGET:  Player
Q_PROPERTY:  m_speed Value:  QVariant(int, 30)
Q_PROPERTY:  m_carType Value:  QVariant(int, -1204931552)
Q_PROPERTY:  p2d Value:  QVariant(P2D*, )
Pointer received is:  0x7ffdb82e3418
Q_GADGET:  P2D
Q_PROPERTY:  m_x Value:  QVariant(float, 2.85026e+31)
Q_PROPERTY:  m_y Value:  QVariant(float, 3.09603e-41)
Value of m_x outside funtion : 10
```

I was expecting the values of m_x and m_y to be 10 and 25, respectively. The pointer that I am passing to `readOnGadget` seems to be correct. The global pointer is just for the example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try using `Q_OBJECT` instead of `Q_GADGET ` and test it if in that case you have this too?

Comment: I always use `Q_OBJECT` , shall I ask why you use `Q_GADGET `?  means What advantage does it create in your program over it?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R thanks for the reply. I tested here and I can't use Q_OBJECT  because I have a struct, not a class. Q_GADGET allows me to access the struct with the meta-object system without inheriting a Q_OBJECT.

Comment: Yes ,  thanks , I didn't knows that.